# How to filter data only in the visible page of the table which is having filter in the header in Tabulator

Tags: search, filter, datatables, pagination, tabulator

I have a table in which i display 5 rows per page.If searched for a value it is fetching results from complete data table.it has to search only from the displayed page in tabulator.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to filter only the current page. If you have a look at the [Row Management Pipeline Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/lifecycle#row) you will see that Tabulator first filters data and then paginates the data that passes the filter.

In order to do this you would need to filter data outside of the table and then paginate it.